# SuperUser accounts exclusion

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

Why is superuser not showing up in my profile under accounts?  I have 3 StackExchange accounts, and ran into some trouble with this one after attempting to create the account 3 times when the first time was successful.  Would this be enough to affect my StackExchange profile?  It's trivial, but I'm kind of interested in fixing it

Comment: Well, it *does* show up now – you have three accounts linked to your user profile.

Comment: Some server error, probably.  It was migrated from superuser to the meta category 5 minutes ago.  That's probably when it was fixed; you looked 3 minutes ago.  I'll take down the question tomorrow.

Comment: The Super User account was successfully merged with your existing OpenID login at 21:09 GMT, so it actually should have been working before you asked the question.

Comment: Might have been cache or perhaps a scheduled migration between servers.